# Position absolute is not working in blackberry mobile app

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, blackberry, mobile-application

I fixed position absolute to display my image to full screen. But in Blackberry the image not coming fully it getting cut.i.e it is coming half of the page...this is common code for ios, Windows & android.this code working fine in all 3 platform except blackberry.if i removed position:absolute it works fine in blackberry but it affects other 3 platforms.i.e.the image cut in other 3 platform...This is my code..

HTML:

```
  <div class="imageBg" id="">
    <div class="ui-grid-a">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <span>Block a</span>
      <div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">
        <span>Block b</span>
      <div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageBg    {background: url(../images/texture_bg.png) repeat;width:100%;position: absolute;height:100%;}
```

If there is any some other way to dispaly my image to full screen of the page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is with height not position and all.Just replace height with min-height. it wil work.

CSS :

```
.imageBg    {background: url(../images/texture_bg.png) repeat;width:100%;position: absolute;min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you trying this one?
I know from bitter experience that on OS5 the position:fixed and position:absolute can have funky results.
This is due to the fact that OS5 was not using the WebKit engine in it's browsers.

I would seriously consider trying to use some custom CSS for the BlackBerries (especially if it's OS5).